# robot_state_publisher segfault on PR2

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, pr2, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have run into a problem during the uprgade of our PR2 from Ludic/Electric to Precise/Groovy.

When running robot start, the robot_state_publisher segfaults immediately. From looking at the log file it appears to successfully parse the URDF, successfully adding r_forearm_cam_optical_frame_joint, which is the last joint in the file.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77096/robot_state_publisher-segfault-on-pr2/) by [evan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1278/evan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This appears to be fixed in the newest ROS Groovy packages and was resolved by upgrading all packages on both the basestation and pr2 machines.

---

Originally posted by [evan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1278/evan/) with karma: 41 on 2013-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0